# EntityFramework lazy loading not working in different context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, lazy-loading

I'm trying to understand how lazy loading works in Entity Framework 6. It seems to me that lazy loading only works in a `DbContext` where the "to-be-loaded" property has already been accessed. Please have a look at the example below - the test `LazyLoad_InSameContext` succeeds, while the test `LazyLoad_InDifferentContext` fails.

Is this intended behaviour? Shouldn't both tests succeed?

```
using System.Transactions;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EfTestProject
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Test
    {
        [Test]
        public void LazyLoad_InDifferentContext()
        {
            Team team;
            Employee employee;
            using (var context1 = new Context())
            {
                team = new Team();
                context1.Teams.Add(team);
                context1.SaveChanges();
            }
            using (var context2 = new Context())
            {
                employee = new Employee {TeamId = team.Id};
                context2.Employees.Add(employee);
                context2.SaveChanges();

                Assert.NotNull(employee.Team); // <- This fails!
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void LazyLoad_InSameContext()
        {
            Team team;
            Employee employee;
            using (var context1 = new Context())
            {
                team = new Team();
                context1.Teams.Add(team);
                context1.SaveChanges();

                employee = new Employee { TeamId = team.Id };
                context1.Employees.Add(employee);
                context1.SaveChanges();

                Assert.NotNull(employee.Team); // <- This works!
            }
        }
        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            new Context().Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context() : base("name=Context") { }
        public virtual DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }

    public class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? TeamId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Edit1:**

The test can be "fixed" by adding `context2.Teams.Attach(team);` before creating the employee. I don't understand why this should be necessary though.

```
using (var context2 = new Context())
{
    context2.Teams.Attach(team);
    employee = new Employee {TeamId = team.Id};
    context2.Employees.Add(employee);
    context2.SaveChanges();
    employee = context2.Employees.Find(employee.Id);

    Assert.NotNull(employee.Team);
}
```

**Edit2:**

It also succeeds, if I create the new entity using `context2.Employes.Create()`:

```
using (var context2 = new Context())
{
    employee = context2.Employees.Create();
    employee.TeamId = team.Id;
    context2.Employees.Add(employee);
    context2.SaveChanges();

    Assert.NotNull(employee.Team);
}
```

Comment: Show us the employee entity

Comment: @Mardoxx But the Team is already saved to the DB in Context1. Shouldn't Context2 just load the entity from the DB?

Comment: @Winetradr good question

Comment: @CodeNotFound You can find all entities in the code snippet

Comment: @Winetradr I would expect that as you are constructing the new employee entity directly, it's not using the proxied version (for lazy loading). What happens if you do, after ```context2.SaveChanges();```, ```employee = context2.Employees.Find(employee.Id);```

Comment: @Mardoxx Even after loading the employee from the DB (`context2.Employees.Find(employee.Id);`) the `Team` property is still `null`

Comment: @Winetradr interesting, I'm at a loss!... I would guess that calling attach for the team to the new context adds it to the local cache (change tracker) so then it can automatically grab and assign the related Team object on the .Add()...

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse I'm not assigning any primary keys in the example. The assigned id `TeamId` is a foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

The EF DbContext will not load anything from the database automatically, even with lazy loading enabled. When you associate an entity with a DbContext by Adding it, or attaching it, the DbContext will go through the virtual navigation properties to associate any references it knows about.

For example: Given a Parent/Child relationship where 1 parent has many children and there is a Parent record in the database already with a ParentID of 10.

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
  var child = new Child { Name = "test", ParentId = 10 }; 
  context.Children.Add(child); 
  context.SaveChanges();
  Assert.IsNull(child.Parent);
}
```

Parent ID will be set to 10, but the Parent reference will be null. The Context simply doesn't know about it. If you later load that parent, not even associating it to the entity, presto, the proxy will return it.. The DbContext goes through the loaded entities for anything that might be referencing the loaded parent and associates it. (Behaviour like this is likely why long-lived DbContexts get slow.)

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
  var child = new Child { Name = "test", ParentId = 10 };
  context.Children.Add(child);
  context.SaveChanges();
  Assert.IsNull(child.Parent);
  var parent = context.Parents.Find(10);
  Assert.IsNotNull(child.Parent); // Poof, Parent is now a proxy pointing to the Parent.
}
```

This can get awkward where DbContexts are relatively long-lived as it's knowledge of related entities may vary depending on what may, or may not have been loaded by related code, leading to intermittent NullReferenceExceptions and the like.

This is one good reason to avoid using FK properties in entities that have navigation properties, instead just to use the navigation property with a key mapped behind the scenes or a shadow property. (EF Core)  When you use FKs and navigation properties you need to be aware of some potentially weird looking behaviour when getting information from navigation references after setting or changing FKs. It's generally safer to just deal with the navigation properties.

Comment: So you're saying a lazy loading actually _does not load anything from the database automatically_. Take a look at the code snipped in _Edit 2_. This test succeeds. The Employee is created using `context2.Employees.Create()` and is therefore wrapped in a proxy. It seems to me that proxies have the ability to load directly from the database, whereas non-proxied entities simply cannot do this.

Comment: Edit 1 informs the context of the existing entity so same behaviour as if you load it. Edit 2 is certainly interesting, I don't use DbSet.Create() but a quick test confirms the Child is created as an EF proxy rather than a POCO. The parent reference within the child then automatically lazy-loads when referenced. (oddly you still need to "Add" the child to the DBSet)  So EF will associate references after the fact for POCO created entities that are associated to the context, but not lazy-load them automatically. But by using DbSet.Create the entity is a proxy and will lazy-load.